# Отладка хранимой процедуры в Visual Studio 2017 из проекта на C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2017

Моя хранимая процедура в базе данных иногда возвращает ошибку, хотя видимых предпосылок для этого нет. Поэтому хочется видеть, что происходит внутри хранимой процедуры, отлаживая код на C#.
Как настроить отладку хранимой процедуры в Visual Studio 2017, чтоб была возможность отлаживать хранимые процедуры, вызывая их из кода C#?

Пример кода на C#:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.GetData") { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Id", 1));
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Prm", 0));

using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(_sConnectionString))
{
    try
    {
        sqlConn.Open();
        сmd.Connection = sqlConn;
        try
        {
            DataTable dtRslt = null;
            SqlDataReader reader = сmd.ExecuteReader();
            do
            {
                var dt = new DataTable();
                dt.Load(reader);
                dtRslt = dt;
            }
            while (!reader.IsClosed);
            return dtRslt;
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlEx)
        {

        }
        return null;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

И вызываемая хранимая процедура из базы данных:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetData
  @Id INT,
  @Prm INT
AS
BEGIN
    IF @Prm = 1
        SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE id = @Id;
    ELSE
        SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE id = @Id;
END;
GO
```

Когда исполняется строка `SqlDataReader reader = сmd.ExecuteReader();` по идее по F11 мы должны провалиться в базу данных в выполняемую хранимую процедуру. Как этого достичь?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6784471/5045688

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, не помогло. Установил галочку "Включить отладку SQL Server", понатыкал точек останова где только можно, ходил по F11 - не, не заходит в хранимую процедуру